# use numpy/matplotlib to draw a histogram with range of bottom/top/infinite

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

*I don't think the title is precise enouth. If anyone will modify it, please help me.*

I used to use numpy and matplotlib to draw a distribution diagram. As far as I know, np.histogram can only set the range with a bottom and a top value. But I'd like to make it three values, which are bottom, top and infinite.
For example

```
MW=[121,131,...,976,1400] # hundreds of out-of-order items
b,bins = np.histogram(MW,bins=10,range=(0,1000))
ax.bar(bins[:-1]+50,b,align='center',facecolor='grey',alpha=0.5,width=100,)
```

with these codes, I can draw a distribution diagram in which ten bins locates (0-100,100-200,...900-1000). But there are a few numbers higher than 1000. I want to put them in "(1000 - +∞)". So it seems like to make the parameter of range become (0,1000,infinite/or a number big enough), but it is not available.

A awful way to do is using some tricks such as:

```
MW=[x if x <1000 else 1001 for x in MW]
b,bins = np.histogram(MW,bins=11,range=(0,1100))
```

And change the xlabel of the plot.

Is there any better way to implement it?
If trick is the only way, is it possible to quickly change the xlabel?

Comment: You can try manually specifying the bin widths and making the last one very large. `bins=[0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,10000]`.